# Setting values to dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to load a dropdown based on another dropdown. I'm using the following code for this.

But the dropdown's two values are not properly set for the corresponding form id. Is there any problem in the following code?

Please check and let me know some solutions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dropdown1: $('#dropdown1').val()
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(e) {
        $.get("Search.do", {
            dropdown1: $('#dropdown1').val(),
              action: 'loaddropdown2'},function(variable){
                var wh=variable;
                alert(wh);
                $("#dropdown2").val(wh);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few JavaScript errors in the code. Try the following, and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdown1 = $('#dropdown1').val()
    $('#dropdown1').change(function(e) {
        $.get("Search.do", {
            dropdown1: dropdown1,
            action: 'loaddropdown2'},function(variable){
            var wh=variable;
            alert(wh);
            $("#dropdown2").val(wh);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi..Still not working..I can able to append the values in dropdown.by doing $("#dropdown2").append('<option>'+wh+'</option>'); but $("#dropdown2").val(wh); is not working

Comment: You set the value attribute in the option element. Try this $("#dropdown2").append('<option value="'+wh+'">'+wh+'</option>');

Comment: Note: $("#dropdown2").val("value") will select the option with value "value".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `#dropdown2` is a `<select>` you can't change the options using `.val()`. You have to literally create the `<option>` elements and insert them into the `<select>`. For example:

```
$("#dropdown2").html('<option value="foo">Bar</option>');
```